# How can I raise an item symbol?

Tags: lists, fontsize, itemize, raise

I don't like the appearance of standard `\textbullet`. It's too big. I decided to shrink it using `\footnotesize{}`. Unfortunately, the bullet is not at the center of a line (It's a little lower). How can it be raised? Is there a symbol other than `\textbullet` which represents a dot? `\cdot` is too small, btw.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\footnotesize{\textbullet}}
\begin{document} 
Items:
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remember that `\footnotesize` is *not* a command taking an argument; rather it's a declaration, which is valid until the group in which it's issued ends. The label is typeset in a group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox`:

```
\setitemize{label=\raisebox{.3ex}{\footnotesize\textbullet}}
```

If you want to scale the symbol, you can use `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package; a little example showing both commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\raisebox{.5\height}{\scalebox{0.6}{\textbullet}}}
\begin{document} 
Items:
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for direct usage of `enumitem` ;)